# Why does voltage always lead current by 90 degrees in an inductor?

Tags: ac, inductor, reactance

I have learnt that in an inductor voltage leads current by 90 degrees. However, I do not fully understand why it is 90 degrees.

I have been looking everywhere for more information on why this is so. However, all the sources I found just state the rule.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's really that the current is the time-integral of the voltage, or the voltage is the derivative of the current.  If the current is a sine, then the voltage is a cosine, since that's the derivative of a sine.

The way derivatives and integrals of sinusoids work, each is ¼ cycle, or 90°, phase shifted from the next.

Comment: @Roo, also note: It only works for one pure sine-wave frequency. Inductors are _linear_ devices: You analyze the behavior for an arbitrary periodic driving signal by decomposing the signal into pure sinusoidal components, and then analyzing each component separately.  The 90° shift doesn't apply to the whole signal, but rather, to each component _at the component's particular frequency_.

Comment: I learned about current/voltage lagging/leading when I was 12, and I 'got' the idea of sines & cosines, but would there have been a way to explain that to 12 year old me without assuming knowledge of derivatives and integrals, about which I was clueless?

Comment: @mickeyf I’m reasonably confident that with an acceptable amount of hand-waving and lies-told-to-children, I could teach a 12-year-old who “got” the idea of sines & cosines and their relationship to current/voltage lagging enough about derivatives and integrals to explain this. I myself first learned them (at 16, admittedly) in a physics course where the teacher gave a 15-minute aside at the beginning of the course so we could follow the calculus-based derivations of kinematics. It was clear, and made understanding the real thing so much easier when it came up in my actual calculus course.

Comment: +1. It drives me crazy when EE types talk about leading/trailing by 90° when they really mean this. It's especially confusing when you don't actually have a pure nominal-frequency sine wave, and the 90° inevitably gets mistaken for a quarter-period time shift at the nominal frequency (e.g. 50 or 60 Hz) rather than what it really is.

Answer (score 8):

The bottom line is *the* basic equation for an inductor and that equation applies in any electrical situation: -

$$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

So if the current is a sine wave, the differential of sine is cosine: -

[image]

Hence voltage leads current by 90 degrees. But remember this only applies to AC signal analysis. For instance if you applied a step voltage across an inductor the current rises linearly with time because: -

$$\dfrac{di}{dt} = \dfrac{V}{L}$$

The basic equation describes both AC and transient events.

Answer (score 6):

Also, an ideal inductor with jwL has a positive imaginary part with no further real resistance. So the angle will turn 90°.

Comment: Surprisingly simple way to visualize it.

Answer (score 6):

The 90 degrees phase shift (for sine waves) is only valid for an ideal lossless coil. In practice there is always resistance in play: series resistance of the wire and skin effect, and parallel resistance due to core losses and eddy currents in the wire and other nearby conductors. The phase shift will be less than 90 degrees. In the extreme case, the core losses of special ferrite beads are so high that they behave as resistors for high frequencies.

There is also parallel capacitance, so if you increase the frequency then the combination goes through parallel-resonance (= high impedance) and becomes capacitive with a phase shift going towards -90 degrees. Oh, and then there is magnetic coupling with other nearby inductors...

Never assume that a coil is just a coil.

Answer (score 2):

Current and voltage start from the same physical phenomenon, electromagnetism, but they are totally different effects.

In the inductance, being a coil, a magnetic field is generated by circulating a current through it. This current is maintained if the voltage to the coil is suddenly stopped.

This generates that the current, in the inductance, is constant before sudden changes in the voltage.

This is the reason why the answer of Olin Lathrop makes sense: With an integral of a function that contains a finite jump, a continuous function is obtained that adds terms that allow to absorb the finite jumps.

The physical effect after this behavior can be checked carefully at: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355140/magnetic-field-due-to-a-coil-of-n-turns-and-a-solenoid

What you comment about the degrees of lag is only observed in phasors, but without the why, your knowledge has been lame.

I add: the same effect occurs with capacitors, voltages and currents, due to the reciprocity theorem http://electrical-engineering-portal.com/resources/knowledge/theorems-and-laws/reciprocity-theorem

Comment: as this is an international website, the answer in English language should be enough.

Comment: My mother language is spanish, so, I made a fast answer first, and edit with more information. There is not an electronics stackexchange in spanish, also.

Comment: I hope that whoever downvoted this did so because they found fault with the content, not merely because it included a language other than English. To say "international... English should be enough" comes across as pretty arrogant to me. I did not find that requirement in the guide to the site or FAQ.  (English is my first and by far best language.)

Comment: I studied electronic engineering and physics in Spain. I don't find correct I don't put my knowledge in my native language if it contains severe and correct information in it. I had a hurry a few hours ago, so I couldn't make the translation available. The google translator is enough for you? I hope so.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect a inductor to a voltage, current will start to flow.
Due to the internal counter-voltage of the inductor (wich could be interpreted as some kind of risiatance against the change of the current) the current will only grow slowly - so current lags compared to the suddden change of voltage when you connect it to the voltage. The inductor stores engery in form of his growing magnetic field.